# Why does distorting images improve training on a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, distortion

I cannot understand why distorting an image, e.g flipping it, increasing the gamma intensity would somehow increase the accuracy on neural network.

Within my situation, I am Using a CNN to detect if dogs are present in an image, and I was recommended to add distortion.

Comment: The why is not really a programming question, this is more appropriate at: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not a deep learning expert. But you certainly don't mean add distortion to all of the training set? I think what you are referring to is just standard data augmentation to get a more varied training set. I'd be happy to be corrected by someone if that's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, @Ash is right. You don't distort all the images. If you add it to some of them, the neural network is able to generalize better and therefore be more robust and immune to some noise.

Comment: Or make copies of the images with different augmentations applied to them. For example, you could have 100 training images plus 100 more flipped versions of the training images.